# Using beforeunload and unload together?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I heard that Opera doesn't work with beforeunload. And some earlier versions of IE also. So how can I use these together ? If I use below, it runs 2 times (They all work) in Firefox.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {

});

$(window).unload(function () {

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this. Following example is quite straight forward using a global flag.

```
var hasUnloadBeenHandled = false;

function onUnload() {
  if (hasUnloadBeenHandled) {
    return;
  }

  //Whatever you want to be handled on unload OR on beforeunload

  hasUnloadBeenHandled = true;
}

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
  onUnload();
});

$(window).unload(function () {
  onUnload();
});
```

Comment: Good answer. Using `window.onbeforeunload = onUnload` is recommended [according to this](http://help.dottoro.com/ljhtbtum.php) for cross-browser compatibility. And you are creating two extra functions, bind `onUnload` directly.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use a flag of sort or you can use something like this http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#once

Answer (score 3):

```
function unloadHandler(m){
    alert(m);
}
if ($(window).unload) {
    $(window).unload(function() {
       unloadHandler("unload");
    });
} else if ($(window).beforeunload) {
    $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        unloadHandler("beforeunload");
    });
}​
```

Comment: Well, +1 for the idea, but in console: `$(window).beforeunload` => `undefined`. I think it is clear why.

Answer (score 2):

Im not a Javascript/JQuery guy, but cant you just use a global variable to keep track of whether or not the method should run?

something like

```
var runme = true;
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
    if(runme){


        runme=false;
    }

});

$(window).unload(function () {
    if(runme){


        runme=false;
    }
});
```